# CodeBlocks Windows missing dll libiconv and libz-1

Tags: windows-10, dll, code-blocks

When trying to install CodeBlocks nightly on Windows 10 64 bit, I've landed on links [general procedure for nightly](http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php/topic,23042.0/prev_next,prev.html#new) and [April nightly build](http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php/topic,23234.0.html).

- I've installed MSYS64 and ugraded packages
- I've unzipped the CB zip and set providen dll in the link at the root folder

But when launching CB, I get errors for missing dll

- zlib-1.dll
- libiconv.dll